# How can I generate public and private key pairs within the contract

Tags: keys, public-key

How can I generate public and private key pairs inside my smart contract? Is it even possible to generate key pairs insidet the smart contract?

Comment: if you generate the key pairs, then every body can know the private key, what's your intention？

Comment: If I put  the generator function in private and give persmissions accordingly, Ya I know this is not a good idea but we generate key pairs in scatter(that is  generated  out side of contract )